Is there a more efficient way to get "x-z" slices from a stack of "x-y" images?
I have a CT scan of an object: images with pixels in an x-y grid, one image per z value.
I want to make x-z images, to view the object from a different angle.
The most obvious way to do this: load all the images into a 3D array like bigImageArray[x,y,z] and save the slices bigImageArray[:,y,:] for each value of y.
The problem: bigImageArray would be too large to store in memory.
What's the best way to handle this?
Attempted solution: for each y value, make an empty x-z array, open each x-y image and fill in one line.
This works but is quite slow (lots of file opening/closing).
Adding a python tag since that's what I've been using, but I'm open to using anything

Since this is [tag:performance], please mention at least magnitude of numbers involved (x, y, z).

"Too large to store in memory". How many slices can you store? Because there's something in between reading the whole volume and reading a single line from each slice.

The simplest way would be to use memory-mapped I/O such as np.memmap for bigImageArray.

Instead of "open each x-y image and fill in one line" save only the line as a file (with np.save?), then merge those small single-line files together for each y. This will read and save each pixel only twice.

let's say you can fit n x-y or n x-z images into memory.
Load up n x-y images and use them to write out n width x n x n "blocks".  Repeat until you've covered z.
Then, load up all the blocks that have y=0, and use them to write out n x-z images.  Repeat until you've covered y.

Decompress them all into a format that can be memory-mapped. TIFF is such a format. TIFF itself can store stacks of images. The tifffile package can give you a memory-mapped TIFF as a numpy array.
Yes, this will take up some storage. You'll always have to trade between storage space and decompression time.

You can save storage (with compression) while maintaining cheap-ish access, if you're willing to deal with blocks/tiles of some sort. The advantage with that is that you have fairly compact pieces of the domain, instad of stretching all across it in whatever dimension.
Your current pattern requires you to decompress your entire dataset, because each slice spans two dimensions in their entirety. If it were sliced/tiled differently, you could spare yourself a sizable fraction of that. In the limit, you could store (and compress) each "x stick" on its own. Then you'd still have to decompress all those, but no more than that (and not the entire volume). I hope you get the idea and don't take that to the limit.
Memory access patterns, locality, ... all related concepts. It's unreasonable to elaborate given the question is currently vague as all get out.

Thanks for the response, the files are already saved as TIFF but I'll look into stacking

TIFF can contain compressed data, which makes memory-mapping impossible. a stack can improve things, but need not. memory-mapping all the 2D slices will already be an improvement vs. "loading" these files the normal way.
